# Service fabric cluster inside Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-service-fabric

We're developing microservices application using Azure Service Fabric. There are a few Web API microservices that runs on SF cluster (OnPremise).

**Now we need to create something like Docker container with SF cluster and run there out application.**

It should be done for out front-end developers that work on Mac and do not want to install SF cluster (and it's impossible as I know).

I don't know if it possible, so I need your suggestion. I know that I can run Docker container inside Service Fabric, but I need completely opposite solution.

Maybe the first step should be get one of Docker image, but witch one? *microsoft/windowsservercore* or *microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express*

and then How to install Service Fabric to the image? If someone has the same problems and found the solution please help.

Comment: Not an answer but... Why do your front end developers need service fabric at all? The way I decided we do it, is have pur front end developed just as a normal application (in our case it's a spa that is hosted using express.js in node). This way they can develop locally as they normally would, but then when they deploy to our dev cluster, the deploy script wraps it up as a guest executable and publishes to our dev SF cluster.

Answer (score 1):

> it should be done for out front-end developers that work on Mac and do not want to install SF cluster (and it's impossible as I know).

You can run SF for Linux on a VM on Mac. There's even official documentation for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-mac.
That's SF for Linux that is still not mature as SF for Windows, here are the differences: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-linux-windows-differences
You could also try to wrap SF for Linux in a Docker container, which will run on Mac because docker for mac is kind of a Linux VM anyway.

> Maybe the first step should be get one of Docker image, but witch one? microsoft/windowsservercore or microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express

These Windows container images will not run on Mac (Linux). They will only run on Windows 2016/10.

My suggestion is either have a Windows VM on your Macs or allow them to RDP into a Windows VM for the purpose of SF, or they can issue SF commands remotely on a Windows based SF cluster.

Comment: We don't want to install SF on frontend computers, so perhaps I like the case with SF for Linux in a Docker container. I will try. Thanks for the idea